# Go back to previous activity based on specific time for example after 5 minute later in android I know how to Go back to previous activity.

Tags: android

I have developed simple application in android that has two activity for example I am here now activity two and I want to Go back to previous from current activity. activity based on specific time for example after 5 minute later in android.
Can any one help for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put handler and postDelayed method in your 2nd activity at onCreate method for 5 min like below example

```
 new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
            }
        },(60000*5));
```

after 5 min activity will finish

Comment: PriyankVadariya how can i stop it when i need like removeCallbacks

Comment: Helow PriyankVadariya can you share with me how to solve about this issue

Comment: Create object list Handler handler = new Handler(); and use it after if you want to stop task then user below code  handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);